# Update masterpage literal in masterpage updatepanel with masterpage method from contentpage event handler

Tags: .net, updatepanel, master-pages

How can I use a masterpage method to modify a masterpage control from a contentpage event handler? This is all .Net w/ VB.Net

I have a literal control in the masterpage that contains tracking code. The content page has two updatepanels that control flow through a sign-up form. The event handler of the button in the content page's updatepanel 1 has to change the text in the masterpage literal to signal a conversion.

- With PageLoad on a separate confirmation page (showing that the masterpage method used does in fact work correctly): Using a masterpage method, I can change the literal with a masterpage property on page load: myMaster.myProperty = myValue. Which in the masterpage property says Set myLiteral.Text = GetTheRightText(value)    End Set
- With content page UpdatePanels: By simple assignment I can change the literal thusly: myMaster.myUpdatePanelPropertyOrMethod = myValue Which in the masterpage method or property says myLiteral.Text = value, myUpdatePanel.Update
- With UpdatePanels: anything with the masterpage method results in an empty updatepanel: myLiteral.Text = GetTheRightText(value), myUpdatePanel.Update comes up empty.

Comment: Hmmm.. this is a really good question, I too would really value an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is way late, but I just found an option, as I was looking for something similar.

Create the logic you need to manipulate the Site.Master, then call your sub/function from the content page.

In your Site.Master page

```
public sub DoWork()
'some logic here
End Sub
```

Then in your content page, where ever you need to "do work" place this....

```
TryCast(Me.Master, SiteMaster).DoWork()
```

Hope this helps you, or someone!